Create a Map<Long, CustomObject> , iterating a List<CustomObject>
I've a list of Order which I am fetching from some third part api.
List<Order> orders = fromApi(orderId);

Here is the Order class:
class Order{
     Long orderId;
     Product product
}

Similarly I fetch products also for those orders. Here the key is orderId.
List<Order> orderIds = orders.stream().map(Order::orderId).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Long,Product> userProductMap = fromAnotherApi(orderIds);

Here is Product class:
class Product{
        String productDesc;
}

I want to extract a map with orderId as a key and Order as value(given below), but meanwhile also want to update orders with the product(from userProductMap) in same stream iteration.
 Map<Long,Order> userOrderMap = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(order -> order.id, Function.identity()));

I want to provide some custom implementation instead of Function.identity() so that while putting Order as value in Map here, I take out product from the userProductMap and update in Order and use updated Order in Map as value.

what userId? Neither your Order nor your Product contain that according to your description

I just updated it is orderId not userId.

If you’re obtaining userProductMap by passing a single orderId to fromAnotherApi, then surely all of the Products in the returned Map are just for one Order.  (Though I admit, I’m not clear on what the Long keys in userProductMap represent.)

Instead of Function.identity() you can reference any method that takes an Order as parameter and returns an Order. Just write such a method that does with the passed in Order whatever you want.

what is the key in the userProductMap ?

@VGR just updated the code.

@cyberbrain I update the code for better clarity.

you didn't answer my question: what is the key in the userProductMap - there is a Long from the API call, but you didn't tell us if this is e.g. the product ID or something completely different. Also the word "user" in your map names confuses me a bit, is there a user involved anywhere (I mean in the code, not that a user maybe triggers the whole stuff)?

@cyberbrain key for userProductMap is orderId. and This map is coming as a response from another API. "Similarly I fetch products also for those orders. Here the key is orderId."

sorry, overread this.

As your Product only has a description as element - how would you recognize, which products are "new" but related to the old product that you want to replace? Is there also an ID inside the product? Some external function that can tell whether two instances of a product are the same in a business view, even if they are in different objects?

@cyberbrain assume Product don't have any id as of now at my end. This mapping is coming from another api we can escape this product id as of now.

so then you have to explain, how one can "take out product from the userProductMap and update in Order and use updated Order in Map as value." - how to relate the product from the order with an updated product from the userProductMap ?

I’m not sure Streams are beneficial here, since you are modifying each Order as you add it to a Map.  I would just use a loop:
Map<Long, Order> ordersById = new HashMap<>();
for (Order order : orders) {
    Long orderId = order.getOrderId();
    order.setProduct(userProductMap.get(orderId));
    ordersById.put(orderId, order);
}

If you insist on doing it with a Stream, and if you have the ability to modify the Order class, you can add a chaining method that returns the object itself:
public class Order {
    // [other fields and methods]

    public Order withProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
        return this;
    }
}

which allows you to write this:
Map<Long, Order> ordersById = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getOrderId(),
        o -> o.withProduct(userProductMap.get(o.getOrderId()))));

If you don’t have the ability to modify the Order class, but still insist on using a Stream, you probably need to fall back to using the peek method:
Map<Long, Order> ordersById = orders.stream()
    .peek(o -> o.setProduct(userProductMap.get(o.getOrderId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getOrderId(), o -> o));

This isn’t really what peek is for, so I personally would opt for one of the other approaches.
